# Are involutions in infinite vector spaces always diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, involutions, infinite-matrices

As the title says, I'm wondering if involutions in infinite dimensional vector spaces always have the entire space as its eigenspace? This is of course true for finite vector spaces, but I've never seen any proofs treating the infinite case.

Obviously they need to span the entirety of the space, so intuitively I feel like this should be the case, but I'm not sure how one would go about proving it if that is so.

EDIT: Over the reals, specifically.

Comment: If $T: V \to V$ is the involution, you can write the projections to the eigenspaces as $(T + 1)/2$ and $(T - 1)/2$. This decomposes $V$ into two sub spaces, the first is the 1-eigenspace and the second is the $(-1)$-eigenspace. (This does not work over a field of characteristic 2).

Comment: The question is unclear. There's no singular referent available for "its" in the first sentence.